# std::runtime_error: resolve: Host not found (authoritative) in boost::asio

Tags: c++, macos, boost, boost-asio, resolve

The following code:

```
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

std::string ipAddress;

boost::asio::io_service io_service;
tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
tcp::resolver::query query(boost::asio::ip::host_name(), "");

tcp::resolver::iterator iter = resolver.resolve(query);
```

results in the following error when run on OS X High Sierra using Xcode 9.1:

```
std::runtime_error: resolve: Host not found (authoritative)
```

The value of `resolver` is:

```
(boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver) resolver = {
  boost::asio::basic_io_object<boost::asio::ip::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>, false> = {
    service = 0x00000001023159a0
    implementation = nullptr {
      __ptr_ = 0x0000000000000000
      __cntrl_ = 0x00000001023156c0
    }
  }
}
```

and the value of `query` is:

```
(boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::ip::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >::query) query = {
  hints_ = {
    ai_flags = 1024
    ai_family = 0
    ai_socktype = 1
    ai_protocol = 6
    ai_addrlen = 0
    ai_canonname = 0x0000000000000000
    ai_addr = 0x0000000000000000
    ai_next = 0x0000000000000000
  }
  host_name_ = "iMac.local"
  service_name_ = ""
}
```

The `resolve` function looks like this:

```
iterator resolve(const query& q)
{
  boost::system::error_code ec;
  iterator i = this->service.resolve(this->implementation, q, ec);
  boost::asio::detail::throw_error(ec, "resolve");
  return i;
}
```

so I can see that calling `resolve` with `resolver.implementation` being a `nullptr` is what's causing the problem. However, I don't know why it's a `nullptr`.

This is not a problem on different machines running OS X Yosemite or El Capitan.

Comment: What does `boost::asio::ip::host_name()` return? Is it a valid hostname or IP-address? And if you want to connect to the local host why not simply use `"127.0.0.1"`?

Comment: It returns `iMac.local`

Comment: What if I just want to find out what the IP address is of the machine?

Comment: Your local address is *always* 127.0.0.1. It's the standard address of the local loopback interface.

Comment: The dynamic IP address on the network then.

Comment: What is the reason you want to connect to the external interface? Do you have a service with is listening on that only, not the standard localhost interface? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve by doing what you do? I wonder because maybe there are simpler solutions, solutions that don't require you to get a list of all interfaces and iterate over them to find the one you want (which is possible but not easy).

Comment: I appreciate what you are saying but right now I just want to know why the above code doesn't work on the current machine and it does on other (older) machines running earlier versions of the OS. That code has worked for a long time on those other machines.

Comment: Have you tried to `ping` the host returned by `host_name`? Perhaps it's simply not correctly set up?

Comment: That doesn't work. But it does on the older machine.

Answer (score 1):

Posting an answer in case others have the same problem and end up here.

Finally figured it out, thanks in part to ***Some programmer dude*** asking about pinging the host and then searching based on the fact that ping failed.

This post https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7707202?start=0&tstart=0 states that for some reason .local hostname is kept turned off unless any of the sharing services is active.

Turning them on fixed the problem.